# Java servlet annotations

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any way to use pure Java servlets not spring mvc request mapping to map a URL to a method?

something like:

```
@GET(/path/of/{id})
```

Answer (score 7):

It's also possible with "plain vanilla" servlets (heck, Spring MVC and JAX-RS are also built on top of servlet API), it only requires a little bit more boilerplate.

```
@WebServlet("/path/of/*")
public class PathOfServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        // ...
    }

}
```

That's all. Thanks to the new Servlet 3.0 `@WebServlet` annotation, you don't need any `web.xml` entry.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)